# GCP pub/sub - how to route messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pub/sub topic through which another application publishes some messages. Let's say messages like `CustomerCreatedEvent`.

```
external-app --> pub/sub
```

There is a country code in the message. based on that I would like to split that into 2 different topics.
For ex: US customer into 1 topic and UK customer into another topic.

```
external-app --> pub/sub --> route based on country code
```

Is there anyway to do using GCP services?

Comment: You can create subscription (and not topics) and filter on the attribute of the message (and not on the body content).  If you can add attribute, and if subscription is a better definition than Topic in your question, you can achieve this directly with PubSub, else, you must put a service that read your message republish it in the right service (Cloud Functions is great for that)

Comment: I see.. sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As `guillaume blaquiere` mentioned, you might consider using the [Filter messages from a subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter), where you only receive the messages that match the filter when you receive messages from a subscription with a filter. (Note: You can filter messages by their attributes, but not by the data in the message. And you can have multiple subscriptions attached to a topic and each subscription can have a different filter.)